# Redirect all tabs to login page after logout in one tab with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Currently, I am having a problem with Spring Security as when I open two tabs and I logout in one tab, the session is sure to be destroyed but I can still make some action on the other tab, which is supposed to redirect me to login page instead of letting me make any other action so far.

Not until I refresh the page, it will redirect to the login page as no valid session any more.

I am trying to find a solution to force the other tabs to redirect to logout page without letting the user doing any thing else as they logout in the other tab.

I wonder if we could achieve such a thing with Spring Security configuration?

Below is my **spring-security.xml**

```
<!-- Secure token end point -->
<http pattern="/api/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- secure api service -->
<http pattern="/api/service/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/service/**" method="GET"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager">

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/overviewOfferLetter" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/importOldCandidate" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/RecruitmentEvent" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/questionnaireResultId**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_INTERVIEWER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/evaluation**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_INTERVIEWER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/questionnaireResult" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_CV_SCREENER') or hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/activityLogs" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/oldCandidate" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/advancedSearch" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/listApplicants" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/duplicatedEmail" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/createApplicant" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/jobHistory" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/importOldCandidate" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oldCandidate" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/importApplicant" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_HR')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/index" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=incorrect"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password" 
        />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.axonactive.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" /> 


<authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.axonactive.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider"></bean>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.axonactive.security.AccountPermissionEvaluator" />
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="webExpressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.axonactive.security.AccountPermissionEvaluator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Define LDAP Service -->
<bean id="ldapService" class="com.axonactive.service.implement.LdapService">
    <property name="contextFactory" value="${ldap.contextFactory}" />
    <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
    <property name="securityAuthentication" value="${ldap.securityAuthentication}" />
    <property name="username" value="${ldap.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
    <property name="searchBase" value="${ldap.searchBase}" />
    <property name="searchName" value="${ldap.searchName}" />
    <property name="distinguishedName" value="${ldap.distinguishedName}" />
</bean>
<!-- End LDAP Service -->

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>

<!-- End point filter for client -->
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Client credential authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager alias="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Declare client service -->
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>


<!-- Declare client list -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetailsService">
    <oauth:client client-id="testSystem"
        secret="9346336818f9d382a22ac5d4486fa5ee" scope="read"
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" />
</oauth:client-details-service>


<!-- Config oauth server -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<!-- Declare resource server, where the token token are store -->
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<!-- Store token in memory -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configuration token service , expire in one day, don't support refresh 
    token -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="86400"></property>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

If there is any other files or information you guys need to see, please tell me.

Comment: Your client-side code would have to actively check if the session is still alive and redirect to login if it's not; Spring Security would have nothing to do with it.

Comment: As you said, I have to check if the session is still alive before any action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kryger said, your client-side code would need to check if your session is still authenticated. We have a similar problem with our client app, in that Spring wants to redirect unauthorized request, but our client app is communicating with our server in a "rest-ful" way, so the client app just fails silently to the end user.

We solve this issue by having a second AuthenticationEntryPoint, specifically with [Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html). By using the Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html, all unauthorized request by our client app get a HTTP 403 error vs a traditional Spring security redirect. Then our client app is configured with an interceptor to listen for any 403 errors and prompt the user with a signin.

Here's an example Spring Security configuration using Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint from our WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter config.

```
/**
 * Configures all the AuthenticationEntryPoints for our app
 */
protected DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
  LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> entryPoints = 
        new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
  // entry point for unauthenticated client apps
  entryPoints.put(new SecuredApiRequestMatcher(), new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());

  // entry point for our normal website
  DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingEntryPoint = 
        new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoints);
  delegatingEntryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(SIGNIN_URL));

  return delegatingEntryPoint;
}


/**
 * {@link RequestMatcher} that checks if requested url matches a secured api path.
 */
final class SecuredApiRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    final Map<String, String[]> securedMethodToUrlMap;

    public SecuredApiRequestMatcher() {
        securedMethodToUrlMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        securedMethodToUrlMap.put(GET.name(), SECURED_GET_URLS);
        securedMethodToUrlMap.put(PUT.name(), SECURED_PUT_URLS);
        securedMethodToUrlMap.put(POST.name(), SECURED_POST_URLS);
        securedMethodToUrlMap.put(DELETE.name(), SECURED_DELETE_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String url = UrlUtils.buildRequestUrl(request);
        String method = request.getMethod();
        String[] securedUrls = securedMethodToUrlMap.get(method);
        if(securedUrls != null) {
            for(String securedUrl : securedUrls) {
                if(url.startsWith(securedUrl)) 
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the response from the Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint

> {"timestamp":1430938979916,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access
>   Denied","path":"/api/secured/url"}

Comment: Currently, I do not manage any configuration by Java bytecode, every configuration of mine now is in xml files.
So do you have any other option that has something to do with the xml files.