# Spring security & primefaces Redirect all tabs to login page after logout in one tab

Tags: primefaces, spring-security

plz could some one tell me how to configure my spring security XML files to Redirect all tabs to login page after logout in one tab ??

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you try to complete your question with some more detail, what have you tried, errors you got, and if applicable any relevant snippets of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073812/redirect-all-tabs-to-login-page-after-logout-in-one-tab-with-spring-security

Comment: thanks @JoseGómez for your answer.every thing is working with spring security login , permissions and logout if i open just one tab.  But after login if i open one other tab and I logout from the first tab the first tab is redirected to login page. but the second is not redirected to login page and if i refresh it it go to login page. so what i m asking for is how after clicking on logout link in one tab the other tabs should be redirected automaticlly to login page. i hope you inderstand my question. :D